# How to forbid modification of certain files with git?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I have a file `folder/1/file.txt` in a repository. I don't want to be able to make a commit if that file was modified. I can create a new file `folder/2/file.txt`, but not modify the original. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess you are asking for git hooks: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for you to protect certain files not to be modified.

**Option 1:**

`git update-index --assume-unchanged filename`. This command can temporary certain file during you are working on a branch. But when you want switch to another branch, you should use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged filename` firstly.

**Option 2:**

As Edmundo said, you can use a **pre-commit hook** to check if the protected files are modified. If yes, stop this commit or create copy files of the protected ones and then continue to commit.